# OpenGL - Fast Textured Quads?

Tags: performance, opengl

I am trying to display as many textured quads as possible at random positions in the 3D space. In my experience so far, I cannot display even a couple of thousands of them without dropping the fps significantly under 30 (my camera movement script becomes laggy).

Right now I am following an ancient tutorial. After initializing OpenGL:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
```

I set the viewpoint and perspective:

```
glViewport(0,0,width,height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,0.1f,100.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Then I load some textures:

```
glGenTextures(TEXTURE_COUNT, &texture[0]);
for (int i...){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D,3,TextureImage[0]->w,TextureImage[0]->h,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,TextureImage[0]->pixels);
}
```

And finally I draw my GL_QUADS using:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, q);
glTranslatef(fDistanceX,fDistanceZ,-fDistanceY); 
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(a,b,c);
    glTexCoord2f(d, e); glVertex3f(x1, y1,  z1);
    glTexCoord2f(f, g); glVertex3f(x2, y2,  z2);
    glTexCoord2f(h, k); glVertex3f(x3, y3,  z3);
    glTexCoord2f(m, n); glVertex3f(x4, y4,  z4);
glEnd();
glTranslatef(-fDistanceX,-fDistanceZ,fDistanceY);
```

I find all that code very self explaining. Unfortunately that way to do things is deprecated, as far as I know. I read some vague things about PBO and vertexArrays on the internet, but i did not find any tutorial on how to use them. I don't even know if these objects are suited to realize what I am trying to do here (a billion quads on the screen without a lag). Perhaps anyone here could  give me a definitive suggestion, of what I should use to achieve the result? And if you happen to have one more minute of spare time, could you give me a short summary of how these functions are used (just as i did with the deprecated ones above)?

Comment: You may consider learning about display lists and Vertex Buffer Objects.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Those aren't going to help. His problem is state changes, which buffer objects and display lists don't fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Perhaps anyone here could give me a definitive suggestion, of what I should use to achieve the result?

What is "the result"? You have not explained very well what exactly it is that you're trying to accomplish. All you've said is that you're trying to draw a lot of textured quads. What are you trying to *do* with those textured quads?

For example, you seem to be creating the same texture, with the same width and height, given the same pixel data. But you store these in different texture objects. OpenGL does not know that they contain the same data. Therefore, you spend a lot of time swapping textures needlessly when you render quads.

If you're just randomly drawing them to test performance, then the question is meaningless. Such tests are pointless, because they are entirely artificial. They test only this artificial scenario where you're changing textures every time you render a quad.

Without knowing what you are trying to ultimately render, the only thing I can do is give general performance advice. In order (ie: do the first before you do the later ones):

1. Stop changing textures for every quad. You can package multiple images together in the same texture, then render all of the quads that use that texture at once, with only one `glBindTexture` call. The texture coordinates of the quad specifies which image within the texture that it uses.
2. Stop using `glTranslate` to position each individual quad. You can use it to position groups of quads, but you should do the math yourself to compute the quad's vertex positions. Once those `glTranslate` calls are gone, you can put multiple quads within the space of a single `glBegin/glEnd` pair.
3. Assuming that your quads are static (fixed position in model space), consider using a [buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object) to store and [render with](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) your quad data.

> I read some vague things about PBO and vertexArrays on the internet, but i did not find any tutorial on how to use them.

Did you try the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page), which has a [pretty good list of tutorials](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides) (as well as general information on OpenGL)? In the interest of full disclosure, I did write one of them.

Comment: Wow! The idea to use different image regions to store several textures in one picture is amazing! Will try that.

Comment: Also, as you suggest to get rid of the glTranslate's, it seems that any functionality should be handled by CPU as far as possible, so that GPU has only to do the rendering itself?

Comment: Thank you very much for the list of tutorials! Did not find them directly on google, and the OpenGL wiki is huge and abstruse for an inexperienced searcher...

Comment: @Fejwin: Getting rid of `glTranslate` is more so that you don't have to do `glBegin`/`glEnd` for each quad. You can render many quads within a single `glBegin`/`glEnd` call. Also, there is a "Getting Started" page on the Wiki, linked directly from the wiki's main page. It has the list of tutorials I linked to. So it isn't that hard to find.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I get the point!
What I was wondering - is my performance issue concentrated in the last bit of code that I've shown (the actual displaying of quads), or do I use some deprecated functions in the initialization, too? Or may be my way to load (and store) the textures is outdated? Anything to change?

Answer (score 7):

> I heard, in modern games milliards of polygons are rendered in real time

Actually its in the millions. I presume you're German: "Milliarde" translates into "Billion" in English.

> Right now I am following an ancient tutorial.

This is your main problem. Contemporary OpenGL applications don't use ancient rendering methods. You're using the immediate mode, which means that you're going through several function calls to just submit a single vertex. This is highly inefficient. Modern applications, like games, can reach that high triangle counts because they don't waste their CPU time on calling as many functions, they don't waste CPU→GPU bandwidth with the data stream.

To reach that high counts of triangles being rendered in realtime you must place all the geometry data in the "fast memory", i.e. in the RAM on the graphics card. The technique OpenGL offers for this is called "Vertex Buffer Objects". Using a VBO you can draw large batches of geometry using a single drawing call (glDrawArrays, glDrawElements and their relatives).

After getting the geometry out of the way, you must be nice to the GPU. GPUs don't like it, if you switch textures or shaders often. Switching a texture invalidates the contents of the cache(s), switching a shader means stalling the GPU pipeline, but worse it means invalidating the execution path prediction statistics (the GPU takes statistics which execution paths of a shader are the most probable to be executed and which memory access patterns it exhibits, this used to iteratively optimize the shader execution).